# Matlab: Delete OVERLAPPING Rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, overlap

I need to delete overlapping rows of two matricies in terms of one column.

For example:

Matrix 1:

```
1, 5;
2, 23;
3, 51;
4, 21;
5, 661;
```

Matrix 2:

```
4, 11;
5, 601;
6, 341;
7, 5;
etc.
```

would result in:

Result Matrix:

```
1, 5;
2, 23;
3, 51;
4, 11;
5, 601;
6, 341;
7, 5;
```

Thanks!
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union` with the additional, indexing outputs.

```
x1 = [ ...
    1, 5; ...
    2, 23;...
    3, 51;...
    4, 21;...
    5, 661];

x2 = [ ...
    4, 11;...
    5, 601;...
    6, 341;...
    7, 5];

[~, ixs1, ixs2] = union(x1(:,1), x2(:,1));


xMerge = [...
    x1(ixs1,:); ...
    x2(ixs2,:)];
```

This results in:

```
>> xMerge 
xMerge =
     1     5
     2    23
     3    51
     4    11
     5   601
     6   341
     7     5
```

Comment: Yes, any idea why this may be? I'm also a little confused at how you do this, but am trying to figure it out.

Comment: There was a typo in the original post.  Last edit fixed it, seems to work now.

Comment: Brilliant. Perfect. Thanks so much, saved me so much time with an elegant answer. Accepted!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, keeping always the last occurence in the chosen column:

```
x = [x1;x2];
columnIndex = 1; % column 1 
[~, i] = unique(x(:, columnIndex), 'last');
xMerge = x(i, :);
```

Applies to multiple matrices and different columns to index.